# Display image from material-ui-dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dropzone

I am working on a ReactJS project. I am using material-ui-dropzone (https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-dropzone) in order to upload and display an image. I am done with uploading the image. My only problem is how to display it to an external component from material-ui-dropzone. Is this possible?

Consider this form (sorry for the censored parts):

[image]

If you click "ADD IMAGE" button, it will show a modal, the material-ui-dropzone:

[image]

The image is successfully uploaded but what I want is to display the image here:

[image]

Is this possible? Is it possible to display the image to an external component? Thank you and sorry for the images.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it should be exposed? You should be able to use the URI kept state; you should console log the state value for files to see the syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved it! Have a good day.